# Xpath: Finding node next to node if present

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to scrape a site using a highly varying HTML structure. The information at interest is not encapsulated. The only marker is a span with a target id TARGETID.

Structure is:

```
<h2>
   <span class="TARGETID">TARGETID</span>
</h2>
<p> <!-- this is not always present, could be more p tags --> </p>
<ul> <!-- also not always present, if there, this is what we want --> </ul>
<h2>
   <span class="SOMEIRRELEVANTID">IRRELEVANT</span>
</h2>
```

My approach was:

```
//h2/span[contains(text(), 'TARGETID')]/../following-sibling::ul[1][count(li) > 1][li]//a/text()
```

Which succeeds when a unordered list is present after the TARGETID, but if not, it takes the next unordered list it finds (which makes sense based on the query).

My question is: How can I limit the query to the nodes of two H2's, starting with the one containing a span with the target id and limited by any following H2 with a span of a different id?

Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes exactly. the following `h2`, in the example line 6, would serve as limiter for the query. It should prevent any extraction of `ul`s further away if the `ul`within those `h2`s is not present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//ul[preceding::h2[1][.='TARGETID']]//a
```

will select all `a` elements beneath a `ul` that occurs after a `h2` with string value of `"TARGETID"` but before any other `h2` elements.

So, for this expanded example,

```
<div>
  <h2>
    <span class="TARGETID">TARGETID</span>
  </h2>
  <p> <!-- this is not always present, could be more p tags --> </p>
  <ul> <a href="example.com">link1</a> </ul>
  <h2>
    <span class="SOMEIRRELEVANTID">IRRELEVANT</span>
  </h2>
  <ul> <a href="example.com">link2</a> </ul>
  <h2>
    <span class="SOMEIRRELEVANTID">IRRELEVANT</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

it would select only

```
<a href="example.com">link1</a>
```

and ***not*** `<a href="example.com">link2</a>`, as requested.

Comment: Thank you! I've sligthly edited your solution:
`//ul[preceding::h2[1]/span[@id='TARGETID']]//a`

This was just what I was looking for.